# About the square root of a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a positive bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, that is, $\langle \psi,A\psi\rangle \ge 0$ holds for every $\psi \in \mathscr{H}$. We write this property as $A \ge 0$.

I am reading Reed & Simon's proof of the following result.

**Theorem:** Let $A$ be positive, bounded and linear. Then there exists a unique bounded linear operator $B$ such that $B \ge 0$ and $B^{2} = A$. Moreover, $B$ commutes with every bounded linear operator which commutes with $A$.

Suppose $\|A\| \le 1$. To define $B$, one considers the power series:
$$B = \sqrt{A} = \sqrt{I - (I-A)} = 1+c_{1}(I-A) + c_{2}(I-A)^{2} + \cdots, $$
which is absolutely convergent when $\|I-A\| \le 1$.

My first question is: how to show that $B^{2} = A$? I know that, because the series for $B$ is absolutely convergent, one can square it and write it as:
$$B^{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(I-T)^{n}$$
with:
$$a_{n} = \sum_{m=0}^{n}c_{m}c_{n-m} $$
and $c_{0} = 1$. I also know that:
$$1-z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}.$$

**Question 1:** Is this enough to prove that $B^{2} = I - (I-A) = A$?

**Question 2:** To prove uniqueness, the authors assume $B'$ is another positive bounded linear operator such that $(B')^{2} = A$. Then, they claim that $B - B'$ is self-adjoint. I don't see, however, why this is true. A positive bounded linear operator is only self-adjoint in the case of complex Hilbert spaces, but there is no mention about the underlying Hilbert space to be complex in their theorem. So, why is this true?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the complex Hilbert spaces are considered. In the real case the positivity does not imply the symmetry of operators. In the real case positivity of  $A$ and $\|A\|\le 1$ do not imply $\|I-A\|\le 1.$ The last condition is needed for the convergence of the series defining the square root of $A.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Iirc it's still true that positive operators admit a square root in the real case

Comment: @FShrike The proof provided in OP fails in the real case, i.e. Reed & Simon considered the complex case.

Comment: What about question 1?

Comment: See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/254385).